# multiplying with less calc with different units

Tags: css

Is it possible to do something like:

```
font-size: calc(100vw * 0.005rem);
```

I don’t want to assume 1 rem = 16 px;

What I intend is just to resize automatically my font size based on window dimension and rem without the necessity of using multiple media queries.

For example, let’s say that for a width resolution of 1100px I would like my font size to be 1.5rem, and for 400px to be 1rem, and in the middle will be fine with the proportional size to this rule. I would like to do:

```
font-size: calc(((100vw - 400px)) * 0.000714rem) + 1rem);
```

I’ve tried different approaches but couldn't get it done.

I guess it must be simple or it just can't be.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here. You can automatically resize your the `font-size` of your `body` using `vw`. That will establish your `rem`.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/  Also http://maloweb.com/snippets/responsivestuff.html

Comment: I’ve modified a little my question trying to make it more clear. I don’t want to change the rem of the client, I want to use it combined with the viewport width to get my font size. Maybe it doesn’t make sense…

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a very good reason to calculate the font size, I would suggest calulating it purely based on rem units. Note that viewport-width can change when you flip your mobile from portrait to landscape mode.

Comment: Maybe your right. But what I’m trying to achieve is not to worry about media queries for everything. With the formula that I’ve written in my example you have control over the font size, actually the change may be as big as you want. But with one line I wouldn’t have to worry about my font size any more (at least in some cases). The problem I think are the units, but at the end all are pixels. The question is if Less let us use this ‘mixing’ units before it coverts them to the same one.

Comment: Probably not, as the vw-unit is not known at compile-time.

Comment: Yes, you are right with that. The browser should do it with the CSS file. We can escape the formula in Less. I’ve already tried that before I asked but didn’t work either.

Comment: For what I’ve found it seems it cannot be done.
MDN stays: `Multiplication. At least one of the arguments must be a number`. I may be guessing too much but I think what it means is that only one argument can have units, and the rest must be numbers. If you only have two factors, one of them must be a “number”.